# How to check request.FILES is black or not in Djnago?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am using Djnago.i Have html Form such as below,

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'someaction' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file"  name="image" id="image">
</form>
```

How to check `request.FILES['image']` is Selected or not in djnago view file?

Comment: Wouldn't checking the emptiness of the `request.FILES['image']` is enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
image = request.FILES.get('image')
if image is None:
    # request.FILES['image'] is not posted
```